# Custom font in React-Native Button

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I use a custom FontFamily for a ReactNative Button? This
is the button:

```
 <Button
      title="ACCEDI"
      color={"#008800"}
      marginVertial={10}
      fontFamily={Fonts.Montserrat}
 />
```

but this is not working, the fontFamily is not changing.
How can i change it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in the style property, please:

```
textStyle={{fontFamily: Fonts.Montserrat}}
```

OR

```
titleStyle={{fontFamily: Fonts.Montserrat}}
```

Here are the useful links:

https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e

https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/977

Comment: I tried but it isn't working. The font is working for <Text> and <TextInput> but not for the Button

Comment: Oh, I'd recommend you to use Touchables and Text then
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches#touchables

Comment: <Button title="Test custom font" titleStyle={{ fontFamily:'MarkPro Medium' }} />
Maybe, something like this will help you
https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/977

Answer (score 0):

Try using this link as a reference [custom fonts in react native](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e)

Edit the font folder src in package.json and try this link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set font-family. Look at the source code for button. (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Button.js). They havent exposed any prop for text style.

```
 const {
      accessibilityLabel,
      color,
      onPress,
      touchSoundDisabled,
      title,
      hasTVPreferredFocus,
      nextFocusDown,
      nextFocusForward,
      nextFocusLeft,
      nextFocusRight,
      nextFocusUp,
      disabled,
      testID,
    } = this.props;
```

You can however create a TouchableWithNativeFeedback and add a Text component and give the styles you like.

Answer (score 0):

in font family you simple put the font name

```
fontfamily:'your-font-family'
```